# play sound in c# without using Media Namespace

Tags: c#

Hii...
I know this question is repeated but I could not found what I am searching..
I want to play sound in c# without using System.Media or CoreDll.dll. Is there any way to write a function in c# as it is in COREDLL.dll ?
Please help...

Comment: Why? Why do you want to avoid using the namespace *specifically designed for playing sounds*?

Comment: You can play "a sound" in C# using Console.Beep() ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use P/Invoke to call the corresponding function from the Windows API:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool Beep(UInt32 frequency, UInt32 duration);
```

Comment: Note that this function may not do anything at all on Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-bit. A better solution would be `MessageBeep`. But then, there's absolutely *no reason why anyone* would do this in a C# application in the first place, so it's really a moot point.